# KendoUI TimePicker Format

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I need to specify a list of times from 7AM - 5PM in 15 minute intervals, would I need to do that one by one like this example?

And if so, what does this: 2000, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0 mean?

```
    $("#timepicker").kendoTimePicker({
    dates: [
        new Date(2000, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0),
        new Date(2000, 10, 10, 30, 0)
    ]
});
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer to demonstrate how this can be done both manually using the `dates` property, and programmatically using the `interval, min, and max` properties.  Please let me know if this works for you!

Comment: It works fantastic, thank you for your help and explaining the formatting in easy to understand detail. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To [answer your second question](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp), the `new Date(2000, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0)` bit is constructing new Date objects that are to be stored in Kendo's `dates` array.

`new Date(2000, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0)` will create a Date object like "September 10th, 2000, 10:00 AM".  The months use 0-based indexing.

With regards to the first bit, if you want to use the *dates* property, you could do something like this:

```
var dates = [];

for (var hour = 7; hour < 17; hour++) {
    for (var minute = 0; minute <= 45; minute += 15) {
        dates.push(new Date(2014, 10, 12, hour, minute));
    }
};

$("#timepicker").kendoTimePicker({
    dates: dates
});
```

This would be easier than manually specifying all of the Date objects.  You can supply your own values to the `new Date` constructor, and iterate over those values using a for-loop.  Then you can take the array you just made and pass it to the kendoTimePicker `dates` property.

However, the *best* way is [to let kendoTimePicker do all of the work for you](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/timepicker):

```
    $("#timepicker").kendoTimePicker({
        interval: 15,
        min: new Date(2000, 0, 1, 7, 0, 0),
        max: new Date(2000, 0, 1, 17, 0, 0)
    });
```

Specifying `interval: 15` will ensure that the times are spread out along 15 minute intervals, whereas specifying `min` and `max` will restrict the input range to only display values between the *time* portions of the Date objects supplied to `min` and `max`.